# document.write: how to get generated text of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having something like this:

```html
<div id="myDiv"><script>document.write('SOMETHING');</script></div>
```

Now i want to get "SOMETHING". when i try

```js
$("#myDiv").text();
```

it returns:

```js
<script>document.write('SOMETHING');</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Using `document.write` is considered a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice). Are you sure you can't avoid it at all?

Comment: @CristianTraìna unfortunately that part is not my code. I have no choice.

Comment: I must say, that's a peculiar html layout... I would reccomend you emptied `myDiv` and changed it's content with a script elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `innerText` property. ( `textContent` will not work as expected as it will log all content of the script. )

```js
const div = document.getElementById('myDiv')

console.log(div.innerText)
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"><script>document.write('SOMETHING');</script></div>
```

Comment: and if you want to stick with jQuery since the question was revolving around that just grab the HTMLElement doing: `$("#myDiv")[0].innerText`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, OP is using JQuery and I don't remember if `innerText` is proxied. If OP needs it in JQuery maybe it would worth including it in the answer

Comment: Diego answered it :) thanks

Comment: Your code here, and in my script works perfect. thanks. But my own code, even when i replace it with yours, will fail. have no idea why. ps: i made a loop to read table cells and the content i have problem with is some of tds. tried javascript and jquery. both failed..

Comment: Make sure your code runs after the doc.write code - move your `<script>` code to just before `</body>`.  Snippets do that automatically.